# Anylogic - Scale object in Main

Tags: anylogic

The scale object has surprisingly disappeared from my Main canvas, and it's no longer showing in the tree under the "Presentation" chapter.

Nonetheless the last value that I applied to that scale is still recorded as I can see it in the status bar (1 meters = 10.69px)

Any idea on how to add a new scale object or bring back the previous one, so that I could edit this value?

Thanks a lot in advance
Kind regards

[image]

[image]

I cannot seem to find the scale object in the Palette, and I don't understand the reason why it's not showing in Main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you build a model with a GIS map in `Main`. As soon as you drag that into `Main`, it does not have a `Scale` object anymore, as that is only relevant for non-GIS agent spaces.

For GIS, scale is managed via the GIS map object.

Comment: Thanks Benjamin! You're absolutely right. If I remove the GIS Map, the scale object appears again. My idea was to work in the continuous space to see the manufacturing process, and to add a GIS Map to see the distribution of the finished products through roads, once they get packed and shipped.

Comment: Absolutely possible, but you need to use different agent types for that. Have a Main agent with GIS and embedded agents (`Factory`...) that use normal 2D space. You can NOT do it all in 1 agent type (would be bad model architecture anyway)

Comment: Thanks again! I'll therefore generate the Factory as a separate Agent type within Main, and see if I'm still able to show both overviews (process-level, and logistic-level)

Comment: Sorry to get back to you, @Benjamin: instead of using GIS in Main, with embedded 2d Agents, I decided to do it the other way around, I mean: having the 2d discrete event blocks in Main, and a "gisMap" agent living in Main, on whose definition I've inserted the GIS map. The problem that I have is that once the control is transferred to the GIS agent, the statechart's states are instantly triggered and the vehicles move rapidly to their destinations and back to the factory, instead of making the vehicles move slowly through the map roads. Is this wrong and GIS should always be used within Main?

Comment: Pls always open new questions for new issues, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow . SOF does not work like a forum. Happy to help, but pls turn it into a stand-alone new question so others can benefit as well

Comment: I'll do so, and close this thread right now as "solved". Thanks again for your time in providing great support!